# How to add backgroud image to bootstrap flatly?

Tags: theming

Hi Im not a theming hero,

Im an happy user of drupal8 and bootstap theme flatly.

I would like to have this sitebranding logo as a background image.

[image]

After 2 days of watching youtube tutorials about theming up bootstrap I can;t figure it out where to make the right modifications?

please help

Answer (score 1):

It's best practice to create a child theme on Bootstrap, the css modifications go into your child theme. That way you can update Bootstrap later on, otherwise your alterations would be overwritten by the update. [More info on how to create a child theme can be found here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/creating-a-drupal-8-sub-theme-or-sub-theme-of-sub-theme)

Comment: could I still use flatly while created a subtheme? Or do I have to build a theme from scretch, because theming isn't my nature

Comment: Creating a child theme means you extend the parent theme. In this example the parent theme would be Flatly so you would indeed build on it instead of creating a theme from scratch.

Comment: I have in drupalrootfolder/themes 2 folders custom and bootstrap. Where do I create the child theme or subtheme. Example `mkdir drupalrootfolder/themes/bootstrap/mychild_theme`

Comment: Your contrib theme should be under /themes/contrib/bootstrap. Your child theme should be under /themes/custom/[your_theme_name].

Comment: Ok thnx for your good advice. I hope I can do this ;)

Comment: Once the new child theme is setup it's only a matter of adding the CSS to it and enabling the theme. If this answer helped you please accept it.

Comment: Thnx I will accept it when Im ready. But how do you suggest installing bootstrap? Im doing a vanilla install drupal now for testing.

Comment: like `composer require "drupal/bootstrap:^3.0"` or the `composer require "twbs/bootstrap:^3.0"`